# NetworkX - reference and implementation mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I'm working on a NetworkX code. I'm trying to learn the basics and following the software official reference and doing some simple projects. 
as a part of this process, i created an empty graph and tried to add a path using "networkx.classes.function.add_path". the problem rises when i use the reference notation and compile the source example , presented below :

```
G = nx.Graph()
nx.add_path(G, [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

i get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_path'
```

which i tried

```
dir(nx)
```

and figured out the error was pointing correct as nx does not have a method for adding paths, but doing the same it i found out Graph has this method:

```
dir(G)
```

so i changed the code to :

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_path([0,1,2,3])
```

which worked correctly.
so, my question is :
was the reference wrong about this example or am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you add a link to the relevant reference page?

Comment: thanks man, i see, they have changed the notation. i guess it is a version documentation problem. the online reference points it right, but the pdf version is wrong. thanks

Comment: @Coal_ write it as an aswer

Comment: Ah okay. I'm not sure of the web addresses still, so I suppose you could answer it yourself instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joel for his helps and points.
the previous answer is not correct as i was making a mistake, here i provide the correct answer.
although i had built NetworkX from source , the compiler was using another version provided by anaconda, and not the built version.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Coal_ , i checked the references, it shows a change in documentation that supposedly not been archived in pdf version yet.

PDF version states the notaion incorrect, it is provided in the link below:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_downloads/networkx_reference.pdf

but WEB edition of reference is correct on the example of the method usage , as presented below:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_path.html?highlight=add_path#networkx.Graph.add_path

Comment: Look closer at the URLs.  The .pdf file is for the "latest" version, and when you open it (as of the day you posted this), it says it is for release Release 2.2rc1.dev20180125164803.  The web version you link to is for networkx 1.10. So the problem is not that the .pdf version is out of date.  Rather the problem is that the .pdf is more up to date than your version of networkx.  Try https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_downloads/networkx_reference.pdf to get the older .pdf documentation

Comment: @Joel thanks for your clarification. my links are not correct, i got that wrong. but the problem is still there, as i checked my built version and the PDF version im looking at right now, they both state version 2.0 and both are released in 2017. but still they don't match in some cases, like my example. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks - could you update the links?  It may be worth submitting a bug report if this is right.

Comment: @Joel i don't have access to the setup i had the problem on rn, will update them as soon as i can. thanks again

Comment: @Joel thanks, you were right, i was making a mistake. thanks again